# Kernel option hidden even if the depending options are met

Tags: kernel

I am configuring a kernel (4.19.235) and need the option `NO_HZ_FULL` to be active.

Currently, I only see the option `HZ_PERIODIC` and `NO_HZ_IDLE` in menuconfig. I checked the line "Depends on:" of `NO_HZ_FULL` to see the options requiered, here is the list of it :

```
Depends on: <choice> && !ARCH_USES_GETTIMEOFFSET [=n] && GENERIC_CLOCKEVENTS [=y] && SMP [=y] && HAVE_CONTEXT_TRACKING [=n] && HAVE_VIRT_CPU_ACCOUNTING_GEN [=n]
```

The current status of theses options is :

```
Symbol: ARCH_USES_GETTIMEOFFSET [=n]
  │ Type  : bool
  │   Defined at kernel/time/Kconfig:25

Symbol: GENERIC_CLOCKEVENTS [=y]
  │ Type  : bool
  │   Defined at kernel/time/Kconfig:29
  │   Selected by [y]:
  │   - X86 [=y] 

Symbol: SMP [=y]
  │ Type  : bool
  │ Prompt: Symmetric multi-processing support
  │   Location:
  │ (1) -> Processor type and features
  │   Defined at arch/x86/Kconfig:376

Symbol: HAVE_CONTEXT_TRACKING [=n]
  │ Type  : bool
  │   Defined at arch/Kconfig:495
  │   Selected by [n]:
  │   - X86 [=y] && X86_64 [=n]

Symbol: HAVE_VIRT_CPU_ACCOUNTING_GEN [=n]
  │ Type  : bool
  │   Defined at arch/Kconfig:512
```

Do you know why the option don't appear? Should I edit the .config by hand to add the line by myself?

Comment: because it relies on HAVE_CONTEXT_TRACKING and HAVE_VIRT_CPU_ACCOUNTING_GEN  which are not set to the good values?

Comment: I added the current value of the options. I belive HAVE_CONTEXT_TRACKING and HAVE_VIRT_CPU_ACCOUNTING_GEN are correctly set?

Comment: No? They are both set to n (no) but they are required?

Comment: Ok i get it now, "Depends on:" show the status needed with `&&` and `!` but also the current status with `[=n]` or `[=y] `. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The required options are not met. `HAVE_CONTEXT_TRACKING` and `HAVE_VIRT_CPU_ACCOUNTING_GEN` are both set to `n` (no) even though they are required.